A WYSIWYM/G processor that translates back and forth with LaTeX?
I know that there are WYSIWYM editors that compile to LaTeX, as in this answer.
But I have read that translating from LaTeX to e.g. Lyx does not work well. I haven't tried to learn LyX yet because I'm worried I can't translate it back from LaTeX in case I have to make a bigger change. Are there editors where you can easily translate back and forth?

LyX is a system in it's won right - whilst one can edit LyX files with a general text editor, only LyX knows how to process them. So back-and-forward is never going to be completely smooth.

@JosephWright, but in theory one could compile lyx to latex, and then latex to lyx back when needed, edit further in lyx, and compile back to latex. I've heard that this Latex-to-lyx step doesn't actually work well, but in theory it should be possible for some lyx-like system to do that?

'In theory' is a slippery slope - it's all about what different systems can represent. As LaTeX is not fixed, LyX is never going be able about to parse all possible LaTeX input, so conversion will always have limitations

I disagree with your back and forth argument. Just watch the Latex window in Lyx when you add, load, include something. It does "its own thing". // However, what would you do, should such tool be available?

@MS-SPO, Id write first draft in lyx and then convert to latex and make sure the formstting is correct, and then when I realize I want to make changes to the content (e.g. i notice a mistake or a review requests it or I realize a refactoring would be good), then i convert back to lyx and edit where its easy to see the math.

Probably you should rethink your strategy and verify by some experimental documents. Perhaps you‘ll need the lyx tool for math only in the beginning. With proper Latex handling you will be faster, quickly. // The sooner you drop the visual aspect, the better. Latex isn’t not Word or so, but quite sophisticated typesetting, delegated.

if you want to play  with format conversions, the more complex format should be always the final format.  If you need some changes, edit the source LyX again, never the LaTeX version. LaTeX to LyX may worth if you love/need a WYSIWYM editor and you do not have the LyX source, but a workflow routine of  back and forth is a very bad idea. On the other hand, there  is a  commercial WYSIWYG LaTeX editor.

Oh, it seems that the cited WYSIWYG editor  is not updated since 2018, so ...
